# How to redirect after confirm amazon cognito using confirmation URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I want to redirect to a specific url after the user confirmation in amazon cognito.

When a user sign up he will get confirmation mail with a verification link as follows
[https://<>.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/confirmUser?client_id=<<>>&user_name=<<>>&confirmation_code=<<>>](https://%3C%3Cmy-prefix%3E%3E.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/confirmUser?client_id=%3C%3C%3E%3E&user_name=%3C%3C%3E%3E&confirmation_code=%3C%3C%3E%3E)

If the user clicks the above link it will redirect to confirmation page.

Once the user confirmation is completed the page should redirect to my application.

Please give me some idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 26):

Currently, this redirection can't be done using verification link in email. I tried adding redirect_uri to the verification URL a while back but they do not work.

**Workaround**

- Create an API in Api gateway which takes these 3 parameters and an additional redirect_uri parameter. In the backend lambda, make a GET request to the actual link using the parameters & confirm the user. On success, return a 302 redirect from your API using the redirect_uri as parameter.
- In your userpool, use the custom message trigger to build a link to your API gateway api instead of the default cognito url
- So, verification link would be something like: https://myapi.abc.com/confirm?client_id=somevalue&user_name=some_user&confirmation_code=some_code&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com
- These values are passed to backend lambda which makes a GET request to https://your_domain.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/confirmUser?client_id=somevalue&user_name=some_user&confirmation_code=some_code
- On success, return 302 https://myapp.com from your API Gateway

I know this is a convoluted workaround for such a simple requirement. The best way would be to raise a feature request and hope they support a redirect_uri in the Cognito URL.

**EDIT**

To save your lambda costs, you could also use an HTTP endpoint in your API and make a request to the [cognito service endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region) for your region. Example:

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.ConfirmSignUp
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1

{
  "ClientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ConfirmationCode":"123456",
  "Username":"username"
}
```

Comment: What are the placeholders to use for confirmation_code, client_id, user_name, etc in the URL : https://myapi.abc.com/confirm?client_id=somevalue&user_name=some_user&confirmation_code=some_code&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com - I am unable to locate it in the cognito documentation

Comment: You would need to set this message using a custom message lambda trigger. Confirmation code would be 'event.request.codeParameter', username in 'event.request.userAttributes'. Just log the 'event' object and see all the available values

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-custom-message

Comment: Is this still the case? Why are there callback urls in the App Client Settings in cognito then?

Comment: The callbacks are for authentication i.e login & not confirmation

Comment: Can this same technique be used for forgot password?

Comment: the get request to actual link always response in 200 even when there is error in response "Invalid link provided"

Comment: When user will be redirected to a https://myapp.com is there a way how I can make him authorized without sign-in?

Answer (score 16):

I got this to work with the help of above answer from @agent420 and examining the github issue https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/612

So here is the complete process that I followed.

- First we need to change the verification method to code from link
     since we need to grab the code when confirming the user through
     lambda. To do this in Cognito(AWS Console), go to Message customizations ->
     Verification type, change it to 'Code'.
- Next we will be adding a lambda trigger to be fired before sending
  the email verification. To add a lambda for this go to Lambda(AWS
  Console) and Create a function. Given below is the lambda I used.

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // Identify why was this function invoked
    if(event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_SignUp") {
        console.log('function triggered');
        console.log(event);
        // Ensure that your message contains event.request.codeParameter. This is the placeholder for code that will be sent
        const { codeParameter } = event.request
        const { userName, region } = event
        const { clientId } = event.callerContext
        const { email } = event.request.userAttributes
        const url = 'https://example.com/api/dev/user/confirm'
        const link = `<a href="${url}?code=${codeParameter}&username=${userName}&clientId=${clientId}&region=${region}&email=${email}" target="_blank">here</a>`
        event.response.emailSubject = "Your verification link"; // event.request.codeParameter
        event.response.emailMessage = `Thank you for signing up. Click ${link} to verify your email.`;
    }

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Your email will be sent with the subject and message specified in `event.response.emailSubject` and `event.response.emailMessage`. The user will directed to the url specified in the `url` variable.

- To add the trigger Go to, Cognito(Aws-console) Triggers -> Custom
  message and select the lambda you just created.
- Since the user will directing to our url we can control the request,
  confirm the user and redirect to a url of your choice.

I used a lambda for this with the use of AWS APIGateway. Given below is the code I wrote in nodejs where I used a 301 redirect.

```js
'use strict';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));
var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19', region: process.env.REGION });

module.exports.verifyEmailAddress = (req, context, callback) => {

  console.log('req');
  console.log(req);
  const confirmationCode = req.queryStringParameters.code
  const username = req.queryStringParameters.username
  const clientId = req.queryStringParameters.clientId
  const region = req.queryStringParameters.region
  const email = req.queryStringParameters.email

  let params = {
    ClientId: clientId,
    ConfirmationCode: confirmationCode,
    Username: username
  }

  var confirmSignUp = CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.confirmSignUp(params).promise()

  confirmSignUp.then(
    (data) => {
      let redirectUrl = process.env.POST_REGISTRATION_VERIFICATION_REDIRECT_URL;
      const response = {
        statusCode: 301,
        headers: {
          Location: redirectUrl,
        }
      };
    
      return callback(null, response);
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      callback(error)
    }
  )
}
```

Replace environmental variables `REGION` and `POST_REGISTRATION_VERIFICATION_REDIRECT_URL` with the values of yours according to the requirement.

Comment: Is there a way to "resend verfication email". So e.g. to re-trigger the CustomMessage_SignUp?

Comment: When user will be redirected to `POST_REGISTRATION_VERIFICATION_REDIRECT_URL` is there a way how I can make him authorized without sign-in?

Answer (score 8):

### **Complete setup guide.**

Complete article link:
https://medium.com/@jacobjoy/redirect-user-using-amazon-cognito-confirmation-url-d8ccb11bac75

> Thank you @yasith starting with simple image to make it clear how we are doing this work around,

[image]
**Step 1:** Create a lambda function with the language of your choice, I am going to use node.js for the following example.
Please read Custom Message Lambda Trigger before you proceed, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html
In this example I am handling only for CustomMessage_SignUp you can customise for others like CustomMessage_ForgotPassword etc. as per your requirement.
Copy the below code to your lambda function,

```
// Creating a custom URL for the user
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    if(event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_SignUp") {
        const { codeParameter } = event.request;
        const { userName, region } = event;
        const { clientId } = event.callerContext;
        const { email } = event.request.userAttributes;
        const url = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/redirect'
        const link = `<a href="${url}?code=${codeParameter}&username=${userName}&clientId=${clientId}&region=${region}&email=${email}" target="_blank">Click the link to verify</a>`;
        event.response.emailSubject = "Your verification link";
        event.response.emailMessage = `Thank you for signing up. Click ${link} to verify your email.`;
    }
// CallBack to the lambda for the email trigger
    callback(null, event);
};
```

> **Note:** The const URL should be updated once you have API Gateway setup.

**Step 2:** Under you Cognito Trigger choose the custom message and select the lambda function which you have created

**Step 3:** Create a GET API in your API Gateway
Don’t set any authorization or don’t enable any API key required.

[image]
[image]
**Step 4:** Create another Lambda Function to validate and confirm the user.

```
'use strict';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));
var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    apiVersion: '2019-11-07',
    region: process.env.REGION
});
exports.handler = (req, context, callback) => {
console.log(req);
    const confirmationCode = req.code;
    const username = req.username;
    const clientId = req.clientId;
let params = {
        ClientId: clientId,
        ConfirmationCode: confirmationCode,
        Username: username
    };
//Validating the user
let confirmSignUp = CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.confirmSignUp(params).promise();
//Returning the redirect url
confirmSignUp.then(
        (data) => {
            context.succeed({
                location: process.env.POST_REGISTRATION_VERIFICATION_REDIRECT_URL
            });
        }
    ).catch(
        (error) => {
            callback(error.message)
        }
    )
};
```

Create a node application in the IDE of your choice and then build using npm install and once your application is build.
Create a zip (Inside the root folder 5 file approx. based on your IDE) and upload to your lambda application.

> Lambda Handler method should be = index.handler

Set the following in the lambda env variable

> POST_REGISTRATION_VERIFICATION_REDIRECT_URL REGION

In your Application you are validating the user in your cognito user pool and returning the URL for the re-direct.
Not in Scope: The error scenario can be also handled based on your requirement.

**Step5:** Go back to the API Gateway, Create a GET request and Put in the Lambda function which you have to created in Step4 and update the mapping template.

[image]
[image]

**Step6:** Now we have to redirect the request based on your lambda response,
Under Method Response in the API Gateway delete the 200 and create a 302 and add the response header Location as per the image,

[image]
And then in the Integration Response you need remove the 200 and add the 302 and then add the header Mappings value as **integration.response.body.location** (Be mindful with the character case)
[image]

> Most important Step: Once all setup Deploy the API and update the
> const URL API in the Lambda Function, created in the step1.

Try creating a test user and user must have got email link something like this,
https://xxxx-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xx/xx/xx/redirect?code=xx&username=xxxxx;clientId=xxxxx;region=eu-west-2&email=test@gmail.com

Comment: thank you very much was searching for something like this. anyway, when I open the recieved link from the email I got {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: How to create the node application mentioned in step 4?

Comment: When the user will be redirected is there a way to sign him in?

Answer (score 1):

You can now manually configure a confirmation redirect lambda function when adding the auth resource to your project: `amplify add auth`. [Check it out](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/lambda-triggers#set-up-lambda-triggers)