# How can I customize AWS Cognito default confim message?

Tags: amazon-cognito, email-verification

I am using AWS Cognito to verif users' emails by sending verification links to users' email. After users click the links, a default confirm message "Your registration has been confirmed!" is shown. Is there a way to customize this message?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Currently (late June 2018) this still appears to be [not supported](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=815259&tstart=0). It is a pain because users should be redirected to the app in question after confirming their account, but currently they must navigate themselves.

There is a [proposed workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165344) (essentially customizing the confirmation e-mail to send the user to your own API that performs the confirmation in a lambda), but I have not tried it. There does appear to be demand for this and AWS is aware of it as a feature request. I've seen them adding more customization abilities to the Cognito console recently, so keep checking there for updates.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Cognito-hosted pages, you only get what you get which is going to vary depending upon when you're reading this message. Here in late 2019, the Cognito-hosted page redirects successful logins and confirmations (of phone/email) to whatever you specified as the redirect URL.

My issue is similar. After the user signs up, I want to customize the CSS of the confirmation page which doesn't appear possible. The confirmation page isn't great because it means that if the user closes the confirmation code entry tab before entering it, then their email is in the system but unconfirmed. And there's no way to confirm it. It's stuck. I'd like to have giant red letters that say "DO NOT CLOSE THIS CONFIRMATION TAB. CHECK YOUR EMAIL FIRST!" but there doesn't appear to be any way to do this at present.

**The solution to any of these "how do I customize X of the Cognito-hosted flow" is** either (a) look in the available UI customizations or (b) if they aren't available, change to an entirely hosted flow (still Cognito... just using your own pages and URLs).