# How to redirect to my website link after successful email verification by cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses, api-gateway

I am using aws cognito service with lambda function in python to verify and signup user when user click on verification link of email but the problem i am facing is

1. in email images are not showing up.
2. when user clicks on verification link it goes to the cogito default success page where it says user verified but instead of this i want that it should redirect to my website

i have already tried to append redirect_url="{url}" in url but it doesn't work seems like their is no property of aws to do redirect like that

1. i want that my image urls works and images shows perfectly in email
2. it should redirect to my website when verification is successful

Comment: At the moment there is no option for that, but there are some workaround for tackle the problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159568/how-to-redirect-after-confirm-amazon-cognito-using-confirmation-url)

Comment: i have already checked out that link but the workaround is not working perfect.