# Customize email verification page in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using Amazon Cognito for user authentication. After the user is registered verification email is sent to his email address. After clicking on the email link user is prompted with this in his browser
Once the user confirmation is completed the page should redirect to my application.

[image]

How should I redirect to my application in this registration page?

Comment: Follow this URL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159568/how-to-redirect-after-confirm-amazon-cognito-using-confirmation-url