# How to get Origin URL from AWS API Gateway to my Lambda function for Cognito Custom_signup_message trigger

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, aws-api-gateway

To make my question simple, I am trying to **redirect** verified cognito users back to my website once they verify their email by clicking on **verification link**. Which I implemented using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159568/how-to-redirect-after-confirm-amazon-cognito-using-confirmation-url) and this [amazing tutorial](https://medium.com/@jacobjoy/redirect-user-using-amazon-cognito-confirmation-url-d8ccb11bac75). This is working magically as there is no redirect URI option available in cogntio verification link. The issue I am facing when I have **multiple environment setup** for development, testing, staging and production (also localhost). In this case I want to redirect my user back to original site where they have registered and not on a static link.

Comment: How about saving the redirect uri as custom user attribute in cognito when user is created?

Comment: Where is the option to add that? when the email itself is sent by the lambda function. There is no parameter in that lambda function from which url user requested to register on the website.

Comment: As soon as user is created you are able to update their attributes. You simply need the username and userpoolid and your lambda needs to have permission to make adminupdateuserattributes call.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html