# How to redirect to the url user initially tried after authenticating with aws cognito in angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, angular-router-guards

kindly help me on this scenario,

I am working with an angular application which has aws cognito authentication, here the user will access the app using a dynamic link with query string from an email.

Since the app has not in authenticated state and guard prevent accessing this route, how can I achieve redirecting to the same page, after the authentication flow.

Comment: I think this is currently only possible if you create a custom message trigger and have an api that will handle the redirect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159568/how-to-redirect-after-confirm-amazon-cognito-using-confirmation-url for more details.